# Merge two Dictionary<string, string> in asymmetric way

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionary in C# 6.0 and I'd like to merge them in a smart way.

Take the first dictionary `foo` as:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "10"},
    {"b", "20"},
    {"c", "30"},
};
```

And the second dictionary `bar` as:

```
var bar = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "333"},
    {"e", "444"},
    {"f", "555"},
};
```

I'd like to merge them in one dictionary with this logic:

- If a key is **in `foo` but not in `bar`** ignore it in the new dictionary
- If a key is **in `bar` but not in `foo`**, take it in the new dictionary
- if a key is in **both `foo` and `bar`**, take the value of `foo` in the new dictionary

Here is my expected result:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "10"}, //this comes from foo
    {"e", "444"}, //this comes from bar
    {"f", "555"}, //this comes from bar
};
```

Is there a smart way to handle this problem without forloop (LINQ expressions are fine)?

Comment: Honestly it really boggles me why some people fear loops *and also why other people fear LINQ*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  `HashSet<T>` methods and LINQ:

1)

```
var fooKeys = new HashSet<string>(foo.Keys);
var barKeys = new HashSet<string>(bar.Keys);
fooKeys.IntersectWith(barKeys); // remove all from fooKeys which are not in both
barKeys.ExceptWith(fooKeys);    // remove all from barKeys which are remaining in fooKeys and also in barKeys
Dictionary<string, string> result = fooKeys
    .Select(fooKey => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fooKey, foo[fooKey]))
    .Concat(barKeys.Select(bKey => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(bKey, bar[bKey])))
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

This is safe because both exclude each other. It's also very efficient since these [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx) methods have `O(n)` complexity with two sets.

---

If it's not understandable in your opinion, maybe you like this more:

2)

```
var inBoth = from kv1 in foo
             join kv2 in bar
             on kv1.Key equals kv2.Key
             select kv1;
var onlyInBar = bar.Keys.Except(foo.Keys)
    .Select(b => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(b, bar[b]));
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var kv in inBoth.Concat(onlyInBar))
    result.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
```

The first query uses a join(more readable in query-syntax) which only returns keyvalue-pairs from the first dictionary where the key also exists in the second dictionary. The second query uses `Enumerable.Except` to exclude all from the second dictionary which are in the first. Both, `Enumerable.Join` and `Enumerable.Except` use sets under the hood so they are very efficient.

It's worth noting that due to LINQ's deferred execution both queries are executed only at the `foreach (var kv in inBoth.Concat(onlyInBar))` and not before.

---

Probably the easiest and most readable approach, a "LINQ left-outer-join":

3)

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> defaultPair = default(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
var query = from barKv in bar
            join fooKv in foo
            on barKv.Key equals fooKv.Key into gj_bf
            from bf in gj_bf.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select bf.Equals(defaultPair) ? barKv : bf;
foreach (var kv in query)
    result.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
```

Comment: LINQ is one of my fear :)

Comment: I like LINQ as long as I can use it for writing clean and easily understandable code. if the resulting code is not "easy", I prefer going with for/foreach loops.

Comment: @GianPaolo: maybe you like my other approaches more, especially the last :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I still prefer [my one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35792368/3276027) :) to me, your linq query is still too hard to read, but maybe it's just that my linq skills are not so great.

Comment: @GianPaolo: your's would be great if OP simply wants to merge them. But he has a special requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupJoin` like this:

```
var res = 
    bar
    .GroupJoin(
        foo, 
        kvp => kvp.Key, 
        kvp => kvp.Key, 
        (kvp, g) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, g.FirstOrDefault().Value ?? kvp.Value))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

The trick here is to `GroupJoin` bar with foo! this way, everything from bar will appear in the final result and for same keys the joined result will be an `IEnumerable` of matched results from second collection which in your case is foo and since it is a `Dictionary` so the matched results will contain only one element and all you need to do is to get its value. In case of no match (items in bar but not in foo) the matched results collection will be empty, so `FirstOrDefault()` will return the default value of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` with Key and Value both set to null. So in this case we just get the Value from our first collection (in your case bar).

Answer (score 1):

A (simple) Linq solution:

```
    var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var toIncludeFromFoo = bar.Keys.Intersect(foo.Keys).ToList();
    toIncludeFromFoo.ForEach(x => newDict [x] = foo[x]);

    var toAddFromBar = bar.Keys.Except(foo.Keys).ToList();
    toAddFromBar.ForEach(x => newDict [x] = bar[x]);
```

Comment: Very clean solution! In your answer the link between newDict and toAdd is missing ;)

Comment: This does not what it's supposed to do. You also add all from `foo`. The result dictionary should only contain foo's where the key is also in bar. So your dictionary contains 5 keyvalues. Look at OP's desired result and the requirement mentioned before.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, you're right. I Didn't read correctly the specs

Comment: @GianPaolo: no, that's fine. Similar to my first two approaches but concise. I'm not a fan of `ToList`+`ForEach` because it's creating new collections which require more memory and additional loops. I prefer a simple `foreach` which only executes the queries once and doesn't need additional collections.

Comment: @TimSchmelter neither do I, actually: I would replace the two `ForEach` with a simple `foreach(string key in toAddFromBar) newDict [key] = bar[key];`, avoiding also the two `ToList()`. But OP doesn't like forloop!

Comment: @GianPaolo: true, but he mentioned `for`-loops not `foreach` :) I think he just wanted to see how this problem can be solved without many nested loops which no one will understand afterwards.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I'd like to see a simple way to solve the problem, without many nested loops. I read all your solutions, really interesting

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can be simplified as:

*The result will contain all keys from `bar`, with value taken from `foo` if exists, otherwise from `bar`.*

which translates to something like this:

```
var result = bar.ToDictionary(barItem => barItem.Key, barItem =>
    foo.ContainsKey(barItem.Key) ? foo[barItem.Key] : barItem.Value);
```

or a bit longer, but more optimal:

```
var result = bar.ToDictionary(barItem => barItem.Key, barItem =>
    { string fooValue; return foo.TryGetValue(barItem.Key, out fooValue) ? fooValue : barItem.Value; });
```